# Can I import System.Security.Cryptography.Xml in visual studio 2003?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2003

I'm trying to import a class which imports System.Security.Cryptography.Xml in a project in visual studio 2003, and I get the following message(error)

Namespace or type 'Xml' for the Imports 'System.Security.Cryptography.Xml' cannot be found.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Did you add a project reference to assembly (it's been there since forever).

Comment: Thankyou,  Adding the System.Security reference solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a project reference to assembly solved the problem.